# Swift Images cannot be read in Asset Catalog

Tags: swift, image, assets

I'm trying to save some images into my bundle. The images reads just fine when I save them in the main bundle. 
[in main bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysWE9.png)

However, if I place them into the asset catalog, they can no longer be read.
[In asset catelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23R7C.png)

Below are the codes I use to access them. If I save the pictures inside the asset catalog, the `for item in items` loop doesn't pick up any of the pictures.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fm = FileManager.default
    let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
    let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

    for item in items {
        if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
            pictures.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no documented way to iterate through the images contained in an xcasset file. At build time the assets get compiled to a .car file, but the only way to read images out of the asset is through `UIImaged(named:)`.

If you need to be able to iterate through some resources in this way, it's best to store them in a simple folder inside your bundle.